# Compare "today" date with input date from form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, date, input

How do i compare "today" with another date from an input?
I'm doing something like this, but it won't work, can't figure out what's wrong.

```js
function ControlloGiorniPrenotazione() {
  var today = new Date();
  var date_from = document.getElementById("date_from").value;

  if (today >= date_from) {
    document.getElementById("controllo_giorni").innerHTML = "You cannot select today or the days before.";
  }

}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
  
    <form>

      <input type="date" name="date_from" oninput="ControlloGiorniPrenotazione()">
      <font color="red"><span id="controllo_giorni"></span></font>

    </form>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You have not given the id to `input`

Comment: And since no id then should see error in console for trying to get value from undefined node. Check your console for errors and note them here when you have issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to get the input element by its Id, but it doesn't have one. You can either add it or get the element by some other means.

Next you should convert the value from a date string to a Date object by calling `new Date()` so that you can properly compare it to today's date.

```js
function ControlloGiorniPrenotazione() {
  var today = new Date();
  var date_from = document.getElementById("date_from").value;
  date_from = new Date(date_from)
  if (today >= date_from) {
    document.getElementById("controllo_giorni").innerHTML = "You cannot select today or the days before.";
  }

}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
  
    <form>

      <input id="date_from" type="date" name="date_from" oninput="ControlloGiorniPrenotazione()">
      <font color="red"><span id="controllo_giorni"></span></font>

    </form>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! That was such a newbie miskate of me. I feel such an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get element by id: `document.getElementById("date_from")`, but your `input` doesn't have an `id` attribute. Change you `input` in HTML to this: `<input id="date_from" type="date" name="date_from" oninput="ControlloGiorniPrenotazione()">`, and it will work fine:

```js
function ControlloGiorniPrenotazione() {
  var today = new Date();
  var date_from = document.getElementById("date_from").value;

  if (today >= date_from) {
    document.getElementById("controllo_giorni").innerHTML = "You cannot select today or the days before.";
  }

}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
  
    <form>

      <input id="date_from" type="date" name="date_from" oninput="ControlloGiorniPrenotazione()">
      <font color="red"><span id="controllo_giorni"></span></font>

    </form>
  
  </body>
</html>
```